# Highcharts - custom navigator dragger issue with Safari/IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, highcharts, safari

I couldn't find any posts on this issue, so I figured I'd ask. I'm working with a custom scrollbar/navigator for Highcharts, and I'm currently having display issues in Safari and all versions of Internet Explorer.

Here's how the custom scrollbar should be displayed:

[image]

Here's how it's showing up in Safari/IE:

[image]

As you can see, in Safari/IE, there appears to be a default dragger that displays behind the custom dragger, and I can't seem to figure out how to hide it. Has anyone had this issue before? Here is the code used to create the custom handles on the scrollbar:

```
(function (H) {
  var d = false;

  H.wrap(H.Scroller.prototype, 'init', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });

  H.wrap(H.Scroller.prototype, 'addEvents', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });

  H.wrap(H.Scroller.prototype, 'drawHandle', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    H.each(this.handles, function (handle, index) {
      var element = handle.element;

      if (index == 0) {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.appendChild(parseSVG('<polygon fill="#464644" points="0,28 6.5,28 6.5,23.6 13,14 6.5,3.8 6.5,0 0,0 " stroke-width="0"></polygon>'));
        $(element).attr({'transform': "translate(" + (handle.translateX) + ',' + (handle.translateY - 6) + ')'}).addClass('drag_knob');
      }
      else {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.appendChild(parseSVG('<polygon fill="#464644" points="13,28 6.5,28 6.5,23.6 0,14 6.5,3.8 6.5,0 13,0 " stroke-width="0"/>'));
        $(element).attr({'transform': "translate(" + (handle.translateX - 12) + ',' + (handle.translateY - 6) + ')'}).addClass('drag_knob');
      }
    })
  });

  function parseSVG(s) {
    var div = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'div'),
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    div.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + s + '</svg>;';

    while (div.firstChild.firstChild) {
      frag.appendChild(div.firstChild.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
  }
}(Highcharts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha, I figured it out. For some reason, in IE/Safari, when using this module, some extra elements are added (`<rect>` and `<path>`). So the solution was to add some CSS to hide those elements:

```
.highcharts-navigator-handle-left, .highcharts-navigator-handle-right {
    path, rect {
      display: none;
    }
 }
```